# Retrieving Skills of LinkedIn Users By URL

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have a list of LinkedIn profile URLs. What I want to do is get the list of skills of those users. I'm having difficulty with the request to send.

Here is my request

```
$response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile("::(~,id=". $testProfileID. ",url=". urlencode($testProfileURL)."):(skills)");
```

What I get from that is profile info for the URL I sent in, but I get the skill list for the logged in LinkedIn user. So I get the same skill list for every person. I have been trying to read through the LinkedIn API Docs and on their forums, but to say its confusing is an understatement. Any help is appreciated.